# Git rebase causes branch diversion

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I looked at more posts on git rebase causing branch diversion, but would like to get inputs from you what is best to use : git rebase vs git merge in the following scenario

Consider I have Master branch and branch-A

The branch-A is not just a local branch, but it is a remote branch as well.

Workflow:

```
git co branch-A
git pull
Make some changes to branch-A
git add
git commit
git push
```

Now more changes happened to master

```
git co master
git pull
git co branch-A
git rebase master
```

Now I have bunch of conflicts, git asks me to resolve the conflicts, add and apply git rebase --continue
I resolve the conflicts

```
git add
git rebase --continue
```

Now I get message that your branch and origin/branch-A diverged and have 3 and 1 different commits respectively. Use git pull to merge remote branch into yours. Now I issue git pull from branch-A

```
git pull
```

Now I get bunch of messages for Auto-merging and finally most of the files have conflict and I end up resolving all those conflicts which I resolved before issuing git rebase --continue again. After resolving all the conflicts, I issue,

```
git add
git ci -m "Fixing the conflicts"
git push
```

Now everything works good and all the conflicts are resolved. But for this, I ended up doing the conflict resolution two times, one before the git rebase --continue and other after doing git pull due to branch diversion.

So my question is, since branch-A is remote, is it even right in the first place to issue rebase or should I have just followed,

```
git co master
git pull
git co branch-A
git merge master
<resolve conflicts>
git add
git commit
git push
```

Sorry for long post, but I felt, it would be much more clear to put what I exactly saw. Thanks a lot for going through my post and your responses are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big question is, whether branch-A is used by someone else. If so, you should never ever rebase it, because rebase rewrites history.

You are also mixing rebase with merge, because `pull` does an implicit merge. The only reason to use rebase in this case is to linearize the history.

But then why do you pull after the rebase? You should simply `push --force` and overwrite the history. If you insist...

pull (merge) and rebase are two alternative methods to get to the same merged content, via different histories, though. You should use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for clarifying.